# How can I log FoxPro errors to a text file?

Tags: foxpro, visual-foxpro

***TL;DR*** How can I issue commands to reliably log FoxPro errors to a plain text file when running INSERTs and APPEND FROM commands through ODBC/OLE DB?

I am attempting to write some massaged data back into a FoxPro database. The actual connection to the .dbf's are done by a service written by a colleague - I'm assuming it uses ODBC or OLE DB. I only supply the path to the DBF and the query strings to run. However I am running into some problems with FoxPro, and unfortunately all my experience lies in SQL Server and friends - not FoxPro.

My problem is that simple statements like the INSERT below work fine in Visual Fp, but fail going through the service. I don't get much useful error information back other than "An error occured".

```sql
INSERT INTO "ADDRESSES" (addressid, firstname, lastname) ;
VALUES (55, 'Test', 'Testerson')
```

To make life easier for myself I have tried to issue more commands to make FoxPro log all error info to a text file. Again, this works in Visual FoxPro - but fails silently and does not output a file when run through the service. I've ensured the directory permissions are correct:

```sql
LOCAL lcOldOnError
lcOldOnError = ON("ERROR") && save old error handler

SET PROCEDURE TO [D:\foxpro\errhandler.prg]
ON ERROR DO ErrHandler WITH ERROR(), MESSAGE() 

&& This insert causes a duplicate primary key error: 
INSERT INTO "address book!addresses" (addressid, firstname, lastname) ;
VALUES (1, 'MyName', 'IsError')

ON ERROR &lcOldOnError && restore old error handler
```

The external PRG errorhandler.prg looks like this. It works inside Visual FoxPro:

```
PROCEDURE ErrHandler
    PARAMETERS gnError, gcMsg
    LOCAL aErrInfo[1]
    AERROR(aErrInfo)

    cErrMsg = LTRIM(STR(aErrInfo[1])) + CHR(13) + CHR(10) + aErrInfo[2] + CHR(13) + CHR(10) + aErrInfo[3] + CHR(13) + CHR(10)
    lnFileHandle = FCREATE ([D:\foxpro\errorlog.txt])
    FPUTS(lnFileHandle, cErrMsg)
    FCLOSE(lnFileHandle)
ENDPROC
```

**Any hints or tips would be appreciated, thanks.**

@DRapp, here is my C# code. It is very site specific I am afraid, so don't know if it helps anything:

```cs
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    // Test - not production code!
    var errormessage = string.Empty;
    DataSvc dataService = new DataSvc();
    dataService.AppDataPath = @"D:\foxpro\test\DATA\addresses.dbf";

    const string commandText = "INSERT INTO [address book!addresses] (addressid, firstname, lastname) VALUES (90, [Iam], [Error])";
    var returnValue = dataService.ExecuteCommands(commandText, ref errormessage);

    Console.WriteLine("\nResult:{0}\nErrorMsg: {1}", returnValue, errormessage);
    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

I only get errors of the kind "An error occured" from DataSvc, so that's why I would like to decorate the INSERT statements with some more commands for rerouting error info to a text file.

Answer (score 2):

You mention a service and OleDb/ODBC.  What language are YOU connecting with.. C#.net, VB.net, something else?

However, noticing one thing... if you are doing an insert to the Address Table, and the column "AddressID" is that of an auto-increment column, you CAN NOT provide the ID to be inserted, that is completely under VFP's control, and is possibly erroring-out on you due to that, or the ID already exists.

You may instead need an UPDATE statement, such as

```
UPDATE ADDRESSES set firstname='Test', lastname = 'Testerson'
   where addressid = 55
```

By looking at your answer and added code, it MAY BE as simple as your device connection.  TYPICALLY for DBF stuff, the connection is to the PATH where the DBF files are found, then once connected, you can do anything to the dbfs within that path.  So I would start by changing

```
 dataService.AppDataPath = @"D:\foxpro\test\DATA\addresses.dbf";
```

to

```
 dataService.AppDataPath = @"D:\foxpro\test\DATA\";
```

Then, your command should not need explicit database.dbc reference.  When it is opened, it should automatically open the corresponding database container in case any such triggers and such may be attached.

```
const string commandText = "INSERT INTO [address book!addresses] (addressid, firstname, lastname) VALUES (90, [Iam], [Error])";
```

to

```
const string commandText = "INSERT INTO [addresses] (addressid, firstname, lastname) VALUES (90, [Iam], [Error])";
```

So, the way you have it is like you were trying to do the following

```
insert into D:\foxpro\test\DATA\addresses.dbf\address book!addresses
```

Comment: My application is written in C#. I know about auto increment fields. This is just an example table without auto increment. I'm not using the address table in the actual solution being developed.

Comment: @Grubl3r, can you actually show what you have within C# to better address and simulate.  I too work VFP and C# and can try to do and offer closer to a trackable error for you..

Comment: Thanks, I've appended it to my question. It's quite site specific I am afraid.. 

BTW I tried another avenue that actually worked. I made my own OleDB connection to the FoxPro db, and I was able to write data with no problems - even Memo fields with more than 256 chars and newlines.

Comment: @Grubl3r, revised my answer, and I think it is a simple pathing issue.

Comment: Thank you very much for the effort. Unfortunately I still have the same problem.. Looks like I have to ask my colleague for a closer look at the data service, or use my own OleDB connection.

Comment: @Grubl3r, that may be, and I've posted plenty on using VFP OleDB, and STRONGLY suggest you parameterize all your queries.  Should be very easy to fine via [OleDb][VFP] in a search

Answer (score 1):

You could try building a set of VFP commands and using EXECSCRIPT maybe.

So in C#:

```
var myCommand = @"try" + Environment.NewLine;
myCommand    += @"  open database mydata" + Environment.NewLine;
myCommand    += @"  update addresses set firstname='test' where addressid = 55' + Environment.NewLine;
myCommand    += @"catch to loException" + Environment.NewLine;
myCommand    += @"  set textmerge on noshow" + Environment.NewLine;
myCommand    += @"  set textmerge to c:\temp\vfp.txt" + Environment.NewLine;
myCommand    += @"  \<<loException.Message>>" + Environment.NewLine;
myCommand    += @"  set textmerge off" + Environment.NewLine;
myCommand    += @"  set textmerge to" + Environment.NewLine;
myCommand    += @"finally" + Environment.NewLine;
myCommand    += @"  close all" + Environment.NewLine;
myCommand    += @"endtry" + Environment.NewLine;
```

You may need to do something with escaping backslashes there. Then execute in C# by setting an OleDB Command to myCommand, and executing with ExectuteNonQuery().

Having said all that, when executing in C#, if you wrap in a try ... catch, and catch a type OleDbException, does the InnerException of that not detail what the problem was at the VFP side?